# Counting tilings of a $2\times n$ board

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction

Let $n=>1$ be an integer and consider a $2*n$ board $B_n$ consisting of $2n$ cells,each one having sides of length one. This picture shows $B_{13}$:

For $n=>1$, let $a_n$ be the number of different tilings of the board $B_n$. Determine the value of $a_n$, i.e., express $a_n$ in terms of numbers.

Comment: Turns out this is a homework assignment. See http://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/2804/assignment2.tex.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Consider the rightmost tile(s) of a valid tiling of $B_n$. Either it is a vertical tile or it is two horizontal tiles.

If it is a vertical tile, then removing it leaves a valid tiling of $B_{n-1}$.

If it is two horizontal tiles, then removing it leaves a valid tiling of $B_{n-2}$.

Comment: Looks like famous series :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Given the number of valid tilings of $2 \times 2$ boards and $2 \times 3$ boards, how can we use that to determine the number of $2 \times 4$ boards? In other words, how do the elements of the set of all $2 \times 4$ boards relate to these $2 \times 2$ and $2 \times 3$ boards?

**Solution**: A $2 \times n$ board can be made by adding a vertical piece to the right of a $2 \times (n-1)$ board or adding a $2 \times 2$ block of two dominos lain horizontally to the right of a $2 \times (n-2)$ board. This covers all possibilities of $2 \times n$ boards. In other words, $B_n = B_{n-1} + B_{n-2}$